# Logstash redis configuration not pushing logs to ES

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash, elastic-stack

We are using ELK stack to monitor our logs. I am total newbie to ELK environment, recently i was working on a task where I need to configure Logstash with Redis to push our logs to,

below is the config i am using, the below config works with ElasticSearch but does not work with Redis,

```
 input {
  file {
        path => "E:/Logs/**/*.log"
        start_position => beginning 
        codec => json       
    }
}
filter {
    date {
      match => [ "TimeCreated", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            #"debug" => "true"
            "index_prefix" => "logstash-app"
        }
    }

}
output {
    #elasticsearch { 
        #local env
        #hosts => ["localhost:9200"]

        #preprod env
        #hosts => ["elk.logs.abc.corp.com:9200"]

        #prod env
        #hosts => ["elk.logs.abc.prod.com:9200"]

        #index => "logstash-app"
    #}
    redis { 
        #local env
        #host => "localhost:5300"

        #preprod env
        host => "redis.logs.abc.corp.com"

        #prod env
        #host => "redis.logs.abc.prod.com"

        data_type => "list"
        key => "logstash" 
    }

    if[debug] == "true" {
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug 
        }
        file { 
            path => "../data/logstash-app-%{+YYYYMMdd}.log" 
        }
    }
}
```

I commented the Elasticsearch, with Elastic Search i am able to view the logs in Kibana but with Redis i am unable to see,

Can anyone point me what wrong i am doing ? how could i debug or see if my logs are shipped correctly

Comment: Do you see your logs in Redis? Once in Redis you need to read them back and send them to your Elasticsearch server. Redis is just a persistent store that holds your data until you read it back, it has no tight integration with ES, you need to make it happen.

Comment: I am not sure of that, how can i view my logs in Redis, here Redis is on a different server right ? should i log into it ? If yes how can i see the logs in redis ?

Comment: You should log onto your redis server and then use the [`redis-cli` tool](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) to start exploring your data. In any case, sending data to Redis will not automagically synch it to your ES.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation of [logstash plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-redis.html):

> `host` should be an `array`

```
redis { 
    #preprod env
    host => ["redis.logs.abc.corp.com"]
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash" 
}
```